# How can i using laravel-dompdf package for persian character in laravel?

Tags: laravel, pdf

I have a persian laravel project. I'm using this package for generate pdf in my project it's working fine with english character but not working with persian character.

Comment: Someone has suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This package does not support Persian language, you can using laravel-tcpdf package.
package link: https://github.com/elibyy/laravel-tcpdf